# Как загрузить в memo не текстовый файл?

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Как корректно загрузить в memo cимволы? Обрезает текст. Требуется для логирования http запросов.

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\User\Desktop\photo_2020-11-02_23-32-02.jpg', TEncoding.ANSI);
```

Загрузка в memo картинки delphi:
[image]

.Net fiddler debugger и его memo:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загрузите файл в память, например, в MemoryStream, приведите MemoryStream.Memory к типу PByteArray, обойдите этот массив, преобразуя каждый байт в строку в нужном виде - например, в десятичном или шестнадцатиричном, и вот эти строки уже выводите в Memo.

Если вам нужно то, что на втором скрине, то для каждого байта проверяйте, входит ли он в число печатных символов ASCII 32..127, и для входящих выводите Chr(pb[i]), а для остальных прямоугольник этот

Comment: Почему 127? Верхняя половина ASCII тоже допустима, на втором скриншоте она точно есть.

Comment: @Alekcvp Трудно сказать, что именно нужно выводить - там есть и фита, и перевернутая пятерка. Собственно, шрифт того дебаггера просто не всю таблицу юникода реализует.  Чтобы не гадать, что за шрифт, и что выводить - наверное, проще ограничиться первой половиной ASCII